# Creating a file accessible to only my application in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, file

I am developing an application for a small office to maintain their monetary accounts.
My application can help create a file which can store all the information.
But it should not be accessible to the user other than in my application.
Why? Because somebody may delete the file & all the records will vanish.
The environment is a Windows PC with a single account having admin privilages.
I am developing the application in C++ using the MinGW compiler.
I am sort of blank right now, as to how I can create such a file.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application can modify it, then the user under whose credentials it runs can modify it, period. Also, if he has administrator privileges then you can't stop him from deleting stuff, even if your application runs under different credentials and the file is protected by ACLs.

Now, since the problem seems to be not of security, but of protecting the user from himself, I would just store the file in a location that is "out of sight" enough and be happy with it; write your data in `%APPDATA%\yourappname`<sup>1</sup>, such a directory is specifically for user-specific application data that is not intended to be touched directly by the user.

If you want to be paranoid you can enable every security setting you can find (hide the directory, protect it with a restrictive ACL when the app is not running, open it for exclusive access, ...), but if you ask me it's just wasted time:

- the average user (our target AFAICT) doesn't mess in appdata, since it's a hidden folder to begin with;
- the "power user" who messes around, if sufficiently determined to shoot himself in the foot (or voluntarily do damage), will find a way, since the security settings are easily circumventable in your situation (an admin can take ownership of any file and change its ACLs, and use applications like Unlocker to circumvent file locking);
- the technician that has legitimate reasons to access the file (e.g. he must take/restore a backup of it) will be frustrated by all these useless precautions.

---

1. You can get the actual `%APPDATA%` path by expanding the corresponding environment variable or via SHGetFolderPath/SHGetKnownFolderPath (or whatever replacement they invented for it in new Windows versions).

Comment: Hi Matteo,
If I go to C:/Windows/System32, I can see explorer.exe. So can I delete it & Windows wont be able to prevent it? I am too scared to actually try it :( Hence asking...

Comment: @Cool_Coder: you can, but Windows will restore it immediately thanks to SFP (or however it's called it now), which is a feature reserved for system-critical files (which, by the way, can still be disabled in some way). All the other files can be protected by ACLs, but administrators can circumvent them, since they are the highest privileged users. Heck, even if there were some restrictions in place, an admin has to be able to load drivers, which, running in kernel mode, can do whatever they please and circumvent any artificial limitation.

Comment: Also, is, as it seems, your user has local access to the machine, he can just reboot it, start a Linux live CD and delete whatever he pleases (hence the common motto "local access=root access").

Comment: @Cool_Coder: uhm, nope, it's mostly you that don't get how security works on Windows (and on almost any other current operating system). root/Administrator/the superuser account on any OS must be able to do *anything* the machine can do - otherwise some tasks would be impossible. Also, application-based security is a complicated matter - the user always interacts with data via some software, what makes your software "more special" than Explorer? They both run under the same security token - and anyway, an admin must be able to circumvent that.

Comment: Yes!!!! I almost forgot that... I have used many times to backup personal files in C: after I messed with Windows bootloader

Comment: hmmm understanding now why this is so.

Comment: *"Also, if he has administrator privileges then you can't stop him from deleting stuff"* Umm, that's incorrect. Last time I checked, on windows you can't delete open files, even if you're admin. Administrator can nuke the process that has the file open, but can't nuke the file. You can rename it, copy it, but can't delete it until everybody closes file handle. That's not linux where root is a god.

Comment: Indeed, and on high-security installations the Administrator actions are audited. Naturally the Administrator cannot falsify these audit logs either.

Comment: @SigTerm: the admin has enough privileges to force handles closed with unorthodox means like Unlocker, since he can inject code in any process and load drivers, which can bypass any security measure.

Comment: @MSalters: if the logs are stored on the same machine where he is admin, he can just clean them (or falsify them by direct modification of the event log files, or install a root kit that transparently removes the offending voices). Again, once you can load drivers or start services under the localsystem account, you can pretty much bypass any security measure. There's no such a thing as a "sandboxed admin".

Comment: @MatteoItalia: The key word is "unorthodox". Unlocker is not a part of standard windows system. In the same sense, a user has power to disconnect HDD while system is running, but you wouldn't normally expect something like this to happen.

Comment: @SigTerm: the key word for Administrator is "almighty", and rightly so, which is the reason why I wouldn't bother adding unnecessarily complex security measures to prevent malicious behavior. [Once you gave a user administrator powers, he can do exactly what he wants](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/21/764633.aspx).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: While I agree that "not trusting administrators" is a bad idea, I wouldn't call windows administrator "almighty". "root" on unix-like systems is almighty, windows admin has less power.  Also, I believe that if a user has physical access to machine, he can obtain administrator privilegies or bypass the whole permission thing entirely. Just a few cents.

Comment: @SigTerm: the restrictions to the power of Administrator are just small roadblocks - since he can install and start services that run under the localsystem pseudo-account, he can still get the "real" most-privileged credentials (and, again, an admin can install drivers, perform local kernel debugging, write directly to physical memory and other devices, so this is completely unrestricted access). About local access=root access, I completely agree, and in fact I mentioned that fact in my second comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your application loads on windows boot and opens the file with `dwShareMode` 0 option.

Here is an [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Andrew can you please tell me how to use that attribute, I am new to it.

Comment: See the link in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You would need to give these files their own file extension and perhaps other security measures (I.e passwords to files). If you want these files to be suggested by Windows then you will have to do some work with the registry.

Here's a good source since you're concerned with Windows only:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff513920(v=vs.85).aspx

As far as keeping the data from being deleted, redundancy my friend redundancy. Talk to a network administrator about how they keep their data safe. I'd bet money on them naming lot's of backups as one of their reasons.

Comment: Hi Austin, my concern is that the user can delete the file via Windows explorer! Windows registry or file extensions can stop him in this endeavor AFAIK!

Answer (score 0):

> But it should not be accessible to the user other than in my application.

You cannot do that.

Everything that exists on machine user has physical access to can be deleted if user has sufficient determination.

You can protect your file from being deleted while program is *running* - on windows, you can't delete open files. Keep file open, people won't delete it while your program is running. Instead, they will kill your program via task manager and delete the file anyway.

Either that, or you could upload it somewhere. Data that is not located on physically accessible device cannot be easily deleted by user. However, somebody will have to run the server (and deal with security + possibly write server software). In your case it might not be worth it.

I'd suggest to document location of user data in help file, and you should probably put "!do not delete this.txt" or something into folder with this file.